# There was once a freeware version of Astah* Community, does anybody know where I can download?

Tags: oop, uml, astah

I used to have Astah installed. It was free, but not only professional is available. I replaced the computer and don't have the download.

Are they available from anywhere to download? I would like to work on the UML diagrams in that program, but I don't want to pay for the whole suite.

If it is not available in any old file download sites, are there other free apps that are comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Astah Community Edition download link is http://astah.net/download#community.

From the list of free [UML tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) the most comparable tool seems to be the [Modelio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelio).

Comment: Oh that's great. Thank you for the link. I was able to install the older version, and I will check out Modelio. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If useful, there is a link in the astha.net site (https://astah.net/products/astah-community/) explaining that Astah Community "was discontinued on September 26, 2018", and more:

> you can continue using Astah Community version 6.9 for commercial use
> if you already have it installed on your computer. Distributing a copy
> of Astah Community to someone else is forbidden in the End-User
> License Agreement.

I think that the original Jude software does not have such restriction, and has almost all the major features of Astah community, but I can't find an official place to download it anymore.

Another great tool (open source) is https://www.diagrams.net/, available online and as desktop app.